# Increment in the python print statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to count number of ones in the each line. The works perfect, just have one small issue in order to print the output - I wrote one print statement with for loop:

```
k=0
for k in range(0,17):
 print ("Number of %d ="  %(k)) , count+k
i=0
k=0
```

The counter names I have are `count0, count1`,.....so on

I want to give `count0,count1`... to the print statement with the loop, because if I write *countk* definitely it will take it as a single variable,
How can I increment the counter with the loop.

```
#!/usr/bin python
import sys
f=open('data-hist.txt','r')

num_lines=21
countnew=0
count0,count1,count2,count3,count4,count5,count6,count7,count8,count9,count10,count11,count12,count13,count14,count15,count16=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

i=0
while i < num_lines:
  line=f.readline()
  count=line.count('1')

  if (count==0):
   count0=count0+1
  elif(count==1):
   count1=count1+1
  elif(count==2):
   count2=count2+1
  if (count==3):
   count3=count3+1
  elif(count==4):
   count4=count4+1
  elif(count==5):
   count5=count5+1 
  if (count==6):
   count6=count6+1
  elif(count==7):
   count7=count7+1
  elif(count==8):
   count8=count8+1 
  if (count==9):
   count9=count9+1
  elif(count==10):
   count10=count10+1
  elif(count==11):
   count11=count11+1
  if (count==12):
   count12=count12+1
  elif(count==13):
   count13=count13+1
  elif(count==14):
   count14=count14+1  
  elif (count==15):
   count15=count15+1
  elif (count==16):
   count16=count16+1

  #print count16
  i+=1
k=0
for k in range(0,17):
 print ("Number of %d ="  %(k)) , count+k
i=0
k=0
sys.exit()
```

Comment: You really must read about lists before writing this program.

Comment: `counts = [0] * 17`, then `counts[count] += 1`. Remove all those `if/elif` statements.

Comment: What about the print statement? if I want to print all count values in for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand your meaning,is this you want:

data.txt

```
123
11
23
111
```

Code:

```
from collections import Counter

with open("data.txt") as f:
    print(Counter([Counter(i)['1'] for i in  f.readlines()]))
```

Output:

```
Counter({0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1})
```

Or maybe you want to count 1 in each line:

from collections import Counter

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for k,v in {num: Counter(i)['1'] for num, i in enumerate(f.readlines())}.items():
        print "{0} line got {1} one".format(k+1,v)
```

Output:

```
1 line got 1 "one"
2 line got 2 "one"
3 line got 0 "one"
4 line got 3 "one"
```

Comment: No, what I want to set my count in the for loop to get the count vales of count1, count2, so on

Comment: @hassan So In my example, `{0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1}` is not you want? what do you want to do with `count1`,`count2`

Comment: @McGragy I want to give `count0,count1`... to the print statement with the loop

Comment: @hassan Actually,i don't think it's a good idea,if your data is large,you can't assign so many variables,if `{0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1}` is you want,you can traverse through this dict to print statement.